# How to send string from a spinner through an intent

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am having problems getting the information from a `Spinner` and passing it through an intent to another activity.

The intent sends a bundle which contains a string from an `EditText` and also the item from the `Spinner`.

I think the problem is due to the `getText()` in the line below. However I am not sure how to fix this problem.

```
String messagecolor = editTextcolor.getText().toString();
```

Can anyone offer insight into what the problem is?

```
 package com.example.myfirstapp;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
        public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_COLOR = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE2";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.color_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            // Apply the adapter to the spinner
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                    int pos, long id) {
                // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
                // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // Another interface callback

            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            }
        }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }  

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage (View view)   {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        Spinner editTextcolor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        String messagecolor = editTextcolor.getText().toString();
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        extras.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE_COLOR, messagecolor );
        i.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(i);

    }}
```

Comment: What about it is not behaving as you would expect? Do you know if the value of the `EditText` is making it into the bundle successfully? How are you trying to extract it in the receiving activity?

Comment: If I run it like that it would crash when the the second activity try's to start. If I change the getText to getContext it would carry the activity name and display on the second activity (com.example.app.activity). Yes the value from EditText works as it should. I am extracting it using the following code. However I think that part is working correctly.

Comment: `Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
  String messagecolor = bundle.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE_COLOR);
  String message = bundle.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
`

Comment: I have the answer now but thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are probably facing is that you are not getting the string of the selected item. What you can try is using [`getSelectedItem()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html):

```
String messagecolor = editTextcolor.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

This method *can* return `null`, so you should also have a check for this.